# it seems that redisson distributed lock does not work

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, redisson, distributed-lock

I'm testing whether distributed lock of redisson does work correctly, with kotlin and coroutine.

```
    runBlocking {
        repeat(1000) {
            launch {
                val lock = nonReactiveClient.getLock("lock")
                if(lock.tryLock(5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                    try {
                        val value = test.get()
                        delay(10L)
                        test.set(value + 3)
                    } finally {
                        lock.unlock()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I think that the result value should be 3000, because the distributed lock guarantees that the 'get' and 'set' operation would be executed together, atomically.

But when I tried to get value, I got the following result :

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get test
"3"
```

What am I doing wrong ???

Comment: I don't know reddison, but given you have a try....finally without a catch, is there a danger that something in the try block throws and exception and you never call get?

Comment: You defined lease time = 5sec, and delay 10sec. So lock would be released automatically by the end of delay.

Answer (score 0):

In Coroutines, after `delay`, thread context can be changed.

`lock.tryLock` - thread id - 77

`lock.unlock` - thread id - 88     (wait infinitely)

you can use `forceUnlock()` under diffent thread id